# How to go about incremental scraping large sites near-realtime

Tags: python, postgresql, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape a lot (a few hundred) of sites, which are basically like bulletin boards. Some of these are very large (up to 1.5 million) and also growing very quickly. What I want to achieve is:

- scrape all the existing entries
- scrape all the new entries near real-time (ideally around 1 hour intervals or less)

For this we are using scrapy and save the items in a postresql database. The problem right now is, how can I make sure I got all the records without scraping the complete site every time? (Which would not be very agressive traffic-wise, but also not possible to complete within 1 hour.)

For example: I have a site with 100 pages and 10 records each. So I scrape page 1, and then go to page 2. But on fast growing sites, at the time I do the request for page 2, there might be 10 new records, so I would get the same items again. Nevertheless I would get all items in the end. **BUT** next time scraping this site, how would I know where to stop? I can't stop at the first record I already have in my database, because this might be suddenly on the first page, because there a new reply was made.

I am not sure if I got my point accross, but tl;dr: How to fetch fast growing BBS in an incremental way? So with getting all the records, but only fetching new records each time. I looked at scrapy's resume function and also at scrapinghubs deltafetch middleware, but I don't know if (and how) they can help to overcome this problem.

Comment: Surely there is some structure to how the site is laid out? Are old threads updating or what exactly is the structure? There are numerous ways to approach the problem, checking last-modified  etc.. but without knowing more details of how the sites work it is way too broad of a question.

Comment: Well, that's the problem, different sites handle things very differently. I don't know what information you are missing, but yes, typically (which is even more true for the relevant, bigger ones) they are (or can be) ordered newest entry first and are pushed front when there are replies (which are quite rare). I know it's kind of a broad question, but I also need a solution that is as generic as possible.

Comment: @user1068464, you might include the "incremental scraping" notation into your question to define more precise the nature of your question.

Comment: Great idea, I added that part. Somehow I didn't think of that keyword, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> For example: I have a site with 100 pages and 10 records each. So I scrape page 1, and then go to page 2. But on fast growing sites, at the time I do the request for page 2, there might be 10 new records, so I would get the same items again. Nevertheless I would get all items in the end. BUT next time scraping this site, how would I know where to stop? I can't stop at the first record I already have in my database, because this might be suddenly on the first page, because there a new reply was made.

Usually each record has a unique link (permalink) e.g. the above question can be accessed by just entering `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39805237/` & ignoring the text beyond that. You'll have to store the unique URL for each record and when you scrape next time, ignore the ones that you already have.

If you take the example of tag `python` on Stackoverflow, you can view the  questions here : `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python` but the sorting order can't be relied upon for ensuring unique entries. One way to scrape would be to sort by newest questions and keep ignoring duplicate ones by their URL.

You can have an algorithm that scrapes first 'n' pages every 'x' minutes until it hits an existing record. The whole flow is a bit site specific, but as you scrape more sites, your algorithm will become more generic and robust to handle edge cases and new sites.

Another approach is to not run scrapy yourself, but use a distributed spider service. They generally have multiple IPs and can spider large sites within minutes. Just make sure you respect the site's robots.txt file and don't accidentally DDoS them.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I already check for unique ids before following a link to a speecific record. The problem is more the paginated view, because these are usually just index.asp?page=1. Obviously, I can't skip this link on the next scrape, just because I have visitted this page once. If I understand you correctly, you would just go to calculate how much pages (from the beginning) you would scrape, once you read all records as of now, correct?

Comment: Your scraping order should be : Repeatedly scrape page 1 on each crawl. Go to page 2 only when all entries on page 1 are unique & repeat this.   E.g. Initially you get all pages i.e. `1,2,3,4,5..End`. Next time you crawl, start with page 1, then 2 .. and so on till you hit duplicate records. Then again follow the same order. Start with page 1 & proceed till you hit duplicate records.

Comment: What when page 1 has only non-unique records, but page 2 has unique records? (Because the ones on page 1 got pushed because of a reply.) I probably have to come up with some probabilities, right? Because, theoretically, there could always be X records pushed in front.

Comment: @user1068464 This is site specific. You'll have to make the order of sorting predictable. If the only sort option is by last post, it makes things a bit harder. One possibility is to look at the page source and see if it has an rss stream (search for keyword `rss`).

Comment: Well, different sites have different options available. Some don't allow sorting at all, and some might be even oldest entries first. (Usually the smaller sites though.) I want(ed) to implement as one Downloader Middleware, so I was looking for the most generic solution.